Space requirements for replacement microwave
I am replacing an existing microwave that sits in an opening. Microwave is 52cm wide and 31cm high. Opening is 57.5cm wide and 36.5cm high.
My research says you need 3 inches/7.5cm on each side and top. Is my situation dangerous if I replace with same size microwave.

Some of it depends on use.  Heating up a cup of coffee/tea two times a day, compared to ten kids heating up lunch in a short period of time.  One can probably be a bit tighter.

Make sure you get a model that's made to be built in. Those don't need additional space around them.
Microwaves come in 2 varieties countertop and built-in. the countertop variants are designed to need space around it to dissipate heat away from itself while the built-in variant are made to expel that heat to the front.

Thats a great solution. Thanks.
